# What needs to be changed when we switch Spark from Standalone to Yarn-Client?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

Currently we have a program which is a web service, receiving SQL queries and use `SQLContext` to respond. The program is now in standalone mode, we set `spark.master` to a specific URL. The structure is something like below:

```
object SomeApp extends App
{
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://10.21.173.181:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    while(true)
    {
        val query = Listen_to_query()
        val response = sqlContext.sql(query)
        send(response)
    }
}
```

Now we are going to shift the system to Spark on Yarn, and it seems that we should use `submit` to submit jobs to yarn. It would be strange to deploy such a "service" on yarn which won't stop like ordinary "Jobs". But we don't know how to separate "Jobs" from our program.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So if you just want to submit your jobs to yarn you can just change the master param. However it sounds like you are looking for a long running shared Spark Context and there are a few options for something like this. There is https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver and https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel .

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed it only needs to change the `spark.master` param. I'll observe `spark-jobserver`  after we get our current program work.